# Cannot login on GUI

Tags: debian, x11, xfce, gui

I'm using Debian Jessie with Xfce and cannot login into the GUI as a normal user, root works. I can login on another terminal. I tried to reinstall lightdm, but I still cannot login. After a login attempt, `dmesg` tells me

```
systemd-logind[2638]: New session c4 of user lightdm.
systemd-logind[2638]: Linked /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to /run/user/110/X11-display.
systemd-logind[2638]: Removed session c2.
```

How can I get more information about what's going wrong? What could prevent me from login in?

Comment: What happens when you try to log in? Does the screen go blank for a second and then you are returned to the login screen? Could you post the contents of your `~/.xsession-errors` file?

Comment: Yes, that's what happens. I don't have the file `~/.xsession-errors`. I do have `/root/.xsession-errors` though.

Comment: Well, this kind of thing is usually related to errors in your shell's configuration files. Try renaming `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` and then logging in. Does that help? Do you have any other desktop environments installed? If so, can you login to those?

Comment: try creating new user and check can you login with that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys. I was able to log in with a new user, so I figured something in my home directory must be wrong. I then ran `sudo chown -hR username:username /home/username/` and I'm now able to log in again.

Comment: Usually XFCE/lightdm if what saves me when I break something in my GNOME/GDM installation. So I guess XFCE is herd to break. Good job :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for me was to `chmod +x` this file:

```
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

Source: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=748944#27